# How can you get XML out of a Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

How can you get XML out of a Data Factory?

Great there is an [XML format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-xml) but this is only a **source** ... not a **sink**

So how can ADF write XML output?

I've looked around and there have been suggestions of using external services, but I'd like to keep it all  *"in Data Factory"*

e.g. I could knock together an Azure Function, which could take JSON, and convert it to XML, using an example like [so](https://gordon.byers.me/azure/azure-functions-convert-json-to-xml-with-newtonsoft/)

But how can I then get ADF to, e.g. to this XML to a File System ?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

If you just want to copy, then use binary format is ok. But if you are trying to let ADF output XML, it is not possible.(As the document you mentioned told.)